# Create LOB Tablespace in Db2

Tags: db2, tablespace, lob

I am running below mentioned query for creating LOB tablespace but getting error.
Can anyone check why this error is coming.

Query :-

```
CREATE LOB TABLESPACE RESUMETS IN BLUDB LOG NO CLOSE NO;
```

Error :-

```
SQL> CREATE LOB TABLESPACE RESUMETS IN BLUDB LOG NO;
ERROR near line 1:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CREATE LOB TABLESPACE" was found following
 "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<select>".

Error :-
```

> ```
> db2 =>  CREATE LOB TABLESPACE RESUMETS IN BLUDB LOG NO CLOSE NO
> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
> valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CREATE LOB TABLESPACE" was found following
> "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<select>".
> SQLSTATE=42601
> ```

Comment: Which Db2-server version and platform are you using?  Is it on cloud?  The syntax being used suggests Z/OS , but *are you sure*  your Db2-server is running on Z/OS ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "LOB tablespace" in DB2 for Linux, Unix and Windows. See the `CREATE TABLESPACE` documentation here.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html